# Присвоить полю свой id Yii2

Tags: yii2

Вывожу поле

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'end[]', ['template'=>'{input}'])->textInput(['value'=>'00:00', 'class'=> 'form-control', 'id'=>'ident'])->label(false)->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(), ['mask' => '99:99',]); ?>
```

Как видно, присваиваю ему id, но от не присваивается. Он остается таким, каким его сделает система. Что я сделал не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это всё MaskedInput ломает. Так должно сработать.

```
<?= $form
    ->field($model, 'end[]', [
        'template'=>'{input}',
    ])
    ->textInput([
        'value'=>'00:00',
    ])
    ->label(false)
    ->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(), [
        'mask' => '99:99',
        'options'=>[
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'id'=>'ident',
        ],
    ]);
?>
```